# C program to search for a number and count its occurrences in an array

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement

This code works in a wrong way, I am kind of finding the solution but I can't apply it. I want to separate a line of code that is outside the `for` loop but inside the `if` statement knowing that `if` statement is inside a nested loop.

I mean this line: `printf("\n fianl result %d has appeard %d in the array", j, count);`

```c
int main() {
    int array[10];
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Enter the number you are looking for:\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (j == array[i]) {
            printf("%d is in the array it is in entery %d\n", j, i+1);
            count++;
            printf("\n fianl result %d has appeard %d in the array", j, count);
            printf("Enter another number \n");
            scanf("%d", &j);
        } else {
            printf("%d is not the array", j);
            printf("Enter another number");
            scanf("%d", &j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And in which case are you going to exit the program? What should the user enter  for that?

Comment: The `break` statement will terminate a loop. Then, after the loop, you can test if `i` is < 10 (match was found) else (match not found) and print the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your scanfs out of the for loop so they aren't executed while you are scanning through the array. Entering -1 ends the while loop.

```
// your variables and array setup goes here
...
printf("Enter the number you are looking for:\n");
scanf("%d", &j);
while (j != -1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (j == array[i]) {
            printf("%d is in the array it is in entery %d\n", j, i+1);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("%d is not the array", j);
    } else {
        printf("\n final result %d has appeared %d times in the array", j, count);
    }

    printf("Enter the number you are looking for:\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
}
```

Comment: You should check for -1 directly after `scanf()`...

Comment: Yes, I know, lazy me ; )    Fixed.

Comment: You should set `count` to `0` before the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: @chqrlie I was intending it to be part of the OP's code, where count is already initialized, and the other variables already are setup.

Comment: Indeed, but then `count` must be reset to `0`  when you scan the next number. Defining and initializing local variables too far ahead of usage is a common cause of bugs. `int count = 0;` at the start of the `while` body is a safer choice.

Comment: @chqrlie You're right!  Thanks!

Comment: It worked thank you (mmixLinus) Your code is perfect, but there is a problem that @chqrlie solved. thank you very much all :)